# Problem connecting to webdav share with path in sharename using TRAMP

Tags: tramp

I would like to connect via TRAMP to a webdav share where I have some files. I can mount the share in Gnome 42 (Fedora linux) without a problem and explore it with Nautilus. However, when I try to use TRAMP to connect, Emacs does not seem to find the server.

I am using the following syntax: `/davs:username@server:path`

The webdav share that defines the server name contains a path, that is `service.host.es/sharename`, and the path contains a space (which I cannot remove, since the webdav instance is configured that way), that is `Base Folder/MyFolder`.

How can I investigate the issue or directly solve it?

Comment: A space might be a problem, yes. Best would bve to contact the Tramp team via `tramp-devel@gnu.org`. Debugging is not possible via stackexchange.

Comment: I will contact them, yes. I tend to think that most of the "problems" that I find are due to my not being able to understand how things are done, so I prefer to ask before "disturbing" the people that are doing the work. However, I have asked in a couple of places and the issue seems complicated, so I will ask the pros. Thanks again for your comment.